# Specifying Src for external graphic in XSL

Tags: image, xslt, pdf, relative-path

I am using JSF1.2 framework and converting XML into PDF using FOP engine and XSL stylesheet. as far as string data is concerned, its working perfectly but now i want to embed images in my output PDF. the directory structure is as follows

ProjectDirectory

-src

--resources

---P2O.xsl

-WebContent

--images

---image1.jpg

the following works fine if i place image1.jpg file in d: drive
fo:external-graphic src='url("file:///d:/image1.jpg")'>
/fo:external-graphic>

Since i have to deploy this application on production server so i can not set this path there. My question is that what should i specify in "src" to pick that image file from WebContent/images path

Any example/help in this case would be greatly appreciated.
With Regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/4217517/825783.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem after a brief search. The main point of consideration is the `FOUserAgent` which acts the mediator between the application and FOP processor. The FOP processor does not know the root or base path of your application unless it's defined explicitly. To use a relative path for your images, you need to create an `FOUserAgent` object and specify the base URL for that `FOUserAgent` instance. In my case, I added the following line (noted below):

```java
FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance();

FOUserAgent foUserAgent = fopFactory.newFOUserAgent();

// This is the important line
foUserAgent.setBaseURL("file:///" + FacesUtils.getHttpServletRequest().getRealPath("/"));

Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, foUserAgent, outputStream);
```

where `FacesUtils` is just a custom made utils file I keep in my project. If you do not have any utils file then simply use `FacesContext` to get the `realPath()`.

Now basePath will refer to your WebContent folder and any image can be accessed relatively from there. I now access my images like this in the .xsl:

```java
src='url("images/image1.jpg")'
```

where the images folder lies in WebContent folder.

Comment: Outide of JSF, I use `foUserAgent.setBaseURL("file://" + PDFGeneratorService.class.getResource("/report").getPath());
` along with `src="url('image/logo.png')"` where logo.png lives in `src/main/resources/report/image/logo.png`